# Question about DateAdd function and information

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm currently writing some SQL and have come upon an odd issue.

The code i'm using is:

```
select * from #table1
where datefield = DATEADD(day, -2, getdate())
```

The issue i'm running into is it won't pull any information like this. If I add a '>' to the '=' it pulls information. If I put an exact date into teh query instead of the 'dateadd' piece it pulls the correct records.

I've tested the date parameters and there are matching records for 4/10/2011. But for some reason it just does not like the '= dateadd' in this instance.

I have also attempted to use the 'current_timestamp' string instead of 'getdate' as well with the same results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getdate()` is `1/300` second precise. You are querying for exact times up to (almost) milliseconds.

If your datefield is a `DATETIME` but without actual time parts, use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #table1
WHERE   datefield = DATEADD(day, -2, CAST(getdate() AS DATE))
```

or, better, this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #table1
WHERE   datefield >= DATEADD(day, -2, CAST(getdate() AS DATE))
        AND datefield < DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(getdate() AS DATE))
```

The latter query will return you all records for the date (even with the time portion set).

Comment: that hit it right on the head. thanks for the answer, didn't know it would function like that.

Answer (score 3):

`DATEADD(day, -2, getdate())` returns the time component as well, something like `2011-04-10 16:35:23.437`

You could use `DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(day, -2, getdate())))` to get just the date part if your Sql Server version is less than 2008 (when the DATE type was added)

Answer (score 1):

`Getdate()` returns a `Datetime`, which includes a time portion.  I'm guessing you are matching against just a date.  Try:

`where datefield = CAST(DATEADD(day, -2, getdate())) as DATE)`